# Requiring major mode features results in excessive-lisp-nesting

Tags: key-bindings

Have written a minor mode that resets `outline-regexp`, and `outline-heading-alist` and adds additional keybindings for showing and hiding outline levels.

To get the corresponding major mode `-map` variables I include the corresponding features where the map variables are defined.

The difficulty in whether to use

```
(add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook 'tika-minor-mode nil t)
```

or enable `outline-minor-mode` within `define-minor-mode`

or perform both.

But I am getting an annoying error, namely

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (excessive-lisp-nesting)
  (cons 'tika-minor-mode local-minor-modes)
  (setq local-minor-modes (cons 'tika-minor-mode local-minor-modes))
```

I want that when an elisp file is loaded, `tika-minor-mode` and `outline-minor-mode` are enabled by default.

Where should such a call be placed in my minor made ?

Here is my implementation

```
(require 'emacs-lisp)  ; for emacs-lisp-mode-map

(defun tika-tools ()
   (add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook 'tika-minor-mode nil t))

;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode tika-minor-mode
  (if tika-minor-mode
      (progn (outline-minor-mode 0)
             (tika-tools)
             (outline-minor-mode 1))
    (outline-minor-mode 0)) )

(defun tika-addhook ()
  "Activate minor-mode' automatically for specific major-modes."
  (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'tika-minor-mode))

(provide 'tika)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encountering void-variable sh-mode-map for define-key](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77752/encountering-void-variable-sh-mode-map-for-define-key)

Comment: This is already answered. You only need to `require` the library explicitly if you want both (1) the bindings it defines and (2) additional bindings that you provide. To *add to existing* bindings, those bindings *need to exist*!

Comment: 1. Get rid of all extraneous code from the question. Include nothing that's not used and nothing that's not needed to repro the error. 2. Define everything needed to repro the error. This includes getting the names right - e.g., change `tematika` to `tika` everywhere. 3. Show more of the backtrace.

Comment: A current hesitation is where to put the call to `(add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook 'tika-minor-mode nil t)` if at all needed.

Comment: Hi @Dilna, it's unclear what problem you're trying to solve, here. You ask about hooks, minor modes, an elisp error, and making sure that two minor modes are enabled when you open an elisp file. Are any of these four questions the one you want an answer to here? Or can you reframe all of this into a single question that encompasses your needs?